# Does Mac need JDK (5 or 6) or Eclipse for developing Android Apps?

Tags: java, android, macos

I want to develop Android apps on the Mac, but the information on http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html is confusing. Apart from the android-sdk_r06-mac_86.zip , does the Mac need JDK or Eclipse ?

The [JDK installation page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/index-137561.html) gives a link to Apple site for downloading "Java Developer Preview 10M3222+9M3222", which is a pre-release version. I am not sure whether this is what I need. Also somewhere says Mac has already got Java SDK by default and no need to install extra, which makes more confusing.

Do I need to install the "Eclipse+ ADT Plugin for Eclipse" as well?

---

I just did a check, and not sure whether the following means I do not need to install any extra JDK. Is the Mac's JDK 1.6.0_20 the equivalent of the other platforms' JDK 6?

> $ javac -version
>
> javac 1.6.0_20
>
> $ which javac
>
> /usr/bin/javac
>
> $ ls -la /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/
>
> total 64
>
> .... drwxr-xr-x   9 root  wheel  306 26 May 11:34 A
>
> lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    1 26 May 11:34 Current -> A
>
> lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    3 26 May 11:34 CurrentJDK -> 1.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to install any JDK on Mac OS, there is one installed by default.

you can run the `javac` command to check that the JDK is present.

Usually it's in /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.Framework/Versions/Current/

You still need to install other tools such as android SDK, Eclipse, and its plugins.

Comment: Thanks Colin, I just put on an screenshot as an answer at the same time when you send your answer. So I think my Mac does not need to install the JDK (5 or 6) said on http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html . Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Colin, another question pops out when I am looking for how to install the Eclipse 64bit. Quoted: "If you are on a 64-bit system but are using a 32-bit JVM, then you should download the 32-bit version of Eclipse. Likewise, if you are using a 64-bit JVM, then you should get the 64-bit version of Eclipse."

My Mac is 64bit, with "Intel Core 2 Duo". But how do I check the JVM whether 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: By default your mac uses a 64Bits JVM, you can check this into the "Java Preferences" application, and drag and drop JVM depending on what you want to be used in priority.

Comment: Thanks Colin, I checked the "Java Preferences", yes it is "Java SE 6 -64 bit" on top of (i.e. higher priority I presume) the "Java SE 6 - 32 bit".

Comment: It's exact, the highest JVM has the highest priority